# Is apache killing my process?

Tags: python, lucene, apache, pylucene

I have a strange problem regarding lucene and apache. I am using lucene for full text search and for a search I need to call:

`initVM()`

I found out that after this call nothing gets executed. So this all happens for a http request handled through apache.

Now when I try to do this manually in the interactive command prompt it works fine.

These are some relavent apache configuration lines below:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      150000
MaxClients       150000
MaxRequestsPerChild  40000
</IfModule>


<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         8
MaxClients         1200
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     45
MaxRequestsPerChild  15
</IfModule>
```

***edit***

when executing it manually it creates 9 threads I think:

```
├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash─┬─pstree
│                           └─python───9*[{python}]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What's going on with this question? Did you pick an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is really meant to be for client applications. For a webapp use, you should really use [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which is installed in a separate web container. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is more about how much control you want over your search. But yes, it is worth evaluating if solr fits your needs.